# newbie confused with PCB designing a TO3 transistor

Tags: pcb

hi guys im a first year electronics student with no background on PCB designing or anything and im confused on how to connect this collectors of a to3 transistor into the capacitor[image]

cause the collector the transistor is its body

[image]

i have to fit it all in 2x6 inch pcb

thanks in advance

Comment: Forget about the layout, that's a bad circuit because it's inefficient and has no overload or thermal protection. If you have a choice, change it.

Comment: You don't put TO-3 transistors onto a PCB, if they are expected to dissipate a large amount of heat - and you can bet that those in your circuit will do so. You should put them onto a large piece of heat sink, and wire them to your PCB (you'll have to have holes in the heat sink for the pins of the TO-3).

Comment: How much current and how much voltage are you planning to use on this PC board?

Answer (score 1):

Notice the dot above the capacitor. This connects the output of the PNP TO3 Transistors, the Capacitor Anode, and PIN 3 of the 7812, it's VOUT. This means they are electronically connected. The Capacitor is a filter capacitor for the 7812, for stability. All it needs to be is physically connected to the VOUT trace. Just like any other component.

The TO3 Transistor casing would normally be screwed or riveted onto the PCB. It can be screwed onto a PCB trace, or through the use of a solder tab, a wire can be soldered to another spot on the PCB

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a lot of point in mounting multiple TO3 transistors into a PCB like that (at least in this application).

They're designed to be mounted on a big heatsink, typically with discrete wires going to the pins and through a lug to the case. Occasionally, sockets are used.

Anyway, if you really want to, create big pads on the PCB with holes of appropriate size to take bolts from the TO3 collectors and bolt them down with metal screws and nuts and lock washers. The connection does not have to be perfect since there are emitter ballast resistors.

The TO-3 case has 0.16" diameter holes, so a UNC #6-32 or M3 screws are appropriate.

[image: http://www.microsemi.com/sites/default/files/drawings/to-3.gif]

If you are going to mount the transistors on a heatsink, it is best (thermally) to leave the heatsink connected to the collectors (and insulate the heat sink itself from the case or whatever). If that's not acceptable, you can buy [TO-3 mounting kits](http://www.alliedelec.com/images/products/datasheets/bm/KEYSTONE_ELECTRONICS/70182958.pdf) that have a mica or silicone insulator, nylon shoulder washers and screws. You can then use a ring terminal to connect to each collector.

Comment: Note, though, that it's a good idea to use star washers rather than lock washers, in order to provide good electrical connection to the bolts and PCB.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Hmm.. well I think star washers are a subset of lock washers (aka external-tooth lockwashers), but good point, more teeth are better.

Comment: Also, internal-tooth versions are available. But you're technically correct - "regular" lock washers are split washers, and that's what I was thinking of.